# business profiles vs personal profiles - all_trips Scope (webhook)

Tags: uber-api

Is there currently any way to request or provide authorization for a specific profile?

i.e. I user uber for personal and business - I only want to provide scope permissions for my business account.

** update to add clarification/use case **

I'll create a faux scenario... to help explain

1. Uber Api provides webhooks for the all_trips scope.
2. A user uses uber for both business and personal trips - and has a business profile and a personal profile
3. The company the user works for needs to keep track of time spent in transportation. distance and location dring "business hours" - uber webhooks makes that much easier
4. The user opts-in to authorize the scopes
5. every time a trip is taken, the details are sent to the hook, appropriate data is logged
6. on the users off day, a personal trip is taken - the trip details are sent to the hook and this is also logged - resulting in the question here....

Hope that helps? we only want to receive all_trips for the business profile....

Comment: There is a one-to-many relationship between user accounts and payment profiles. OAuth authorization with the Uber API works on a user-account level. However, if your goal is to define a payment method for specific trips, the POST /v1/requests endpoints (parameter payment_method_id) allows you to do that. Are you more concerned about the data exposed? The GET /v1/payment-methods endpoint exposes only an id, type and description (which is masked). Also, how is that related to the all_trips scope you refer to in your title? Could you be a bit more specific in your scenario?

Comment: updated the q - hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Unfortunately, we don't currently make this feature available via the API. But thanks for your interest and the question, it helps us to understand what the community is looking for so we can prioritize what gets built and released next.

Keep an eye on the Uber Developers blog for news around upcoming APIs.

Comment: thanks - id suggest either specifying business, personal in the scopes or as part of the API app signup; im sure there will be business specific integrations vs personal vs both :)

Answer (score 1):

Today it is not possible to specify the profile when requesting a ride. The rider can select their profile once the ride is in progress.

For details see the api endpoint reference:
https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-estimate

Comment: I'll clarify my question - I'm more interested in the webhooks flow.

Comment: It is not currently possible to receive only the webhook notifications for business profiles. With the all_trips scope you will always receive all trips regardless of requesting app or profile (payment_method).